# In Docker Compose, are environment variables from .env bundled inside the images or are available for container only?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have a docker-compose.yml file locally, and a .env file that contains secrets and variables that are valid for my local environment, I build the stack using `docker-compose build`, I push the stack to an image registry using `docker-compose push`.

Does this mean that any other environment that does a `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up` from that repository will receive an image with the private environment variables already available inside the image (which might contain secret stuff like access tokens)?

Or in other words: are the things defined in the .env file available at image build time or at container runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your Dockerfile, i.e a way you define how to build the image.

If you accidentally copy the `.env` file into the image at build stage (in Dockerfile), it might get uploaded.

If you only use it as a part of docker-compose file (`env_file` parameter), the variables will only be passed to containers at runtime. In such case you will need to make sure that `.env` file exists wherever you decide to run the containers.

Comment: What about using, e.g: `environment: - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}` instead of `env_file:` as part of the service definitions in the docker-compose.yml file. Within the context of my question of "build VS runtime", does it make any difference?

Comment: Env vars that are not defined in a file will not be a part of the image, they will be passed to a container at startup.